# Excluding files in robocopy using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have the below Robocopy script that I am using .What I want to know is that is there a way that I can exclude all files starting with com_ instead of a specific file  during the mirror operation .
Any suggestions are really appreciated.

```
Const ROBOCOPY_PARMS_MIRROR = "/mir /r:1 /w:3 /np /xa:SH /tee /np"
Const ROBOCOPY_PARMS_EXCLUDE_DIR = "bin"
Const ROBOCOPY_PARMS_EXCLUDE_FILE = "com_.txt"
Const sourcePath = "C:\copy1"
Const destinationPath = "C:\copy"
roboCopyParms = ROBOCOPY_PARMS_MIRROR 
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmd = "robocopy " & sourcePath & " " & destinationPath & " " & roboCopyParms  & " /xd " & ROBOCOPY_PARMS_EXCLUDE_DIR & " /xf " & ROBOCOPY_PARMS_EXCLUDE_FILE
ret = WshShell.Run(cmd, 0, true) 
WScript.Echo ret
```

Thanks

Comment: (Try to) Use the `/XF ExFile 
Excludes files matching given names, paths, or wildcard characters.` option

Comment: can you show how to do that in a script..I am not sure what you meant .

Comment: got the answer ..all we need to do is make the file name as com_* and then it excludes all .

Comment: As your command line is prepared for /XF already, using `Const ROBOCOPY_PARMS_EXCLUDE_FILE = "com_*.*"` (mark the wildcard) may solve your problem (NOT TESTED!).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to create your own robocopy script:

```
Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

RoboCopy "C:\copy","C:\copy1"

Function RoboCopy(source,dest)

  Set sourceFolder = fso.GetFolder(source)

  If Not(fso.FolderExists(dest)) Then
    fso.CreateFolder(dest)
  End If

  For Each file In sourceFolder.Files
    If Left(file.Name,3)<>"com" Then
      fso.CopyFile file.Path,dest & "\" & file.Name
    End If
  Next

  For Each subfolder In sourceFolder.SubFolders
    RoboCopy source & "\" & subfolder.Name,dest & "\" & subfolder.Name
  Next

End Function
```